# Yii2 Query : access array elements in object returned by a query

Tags: php, arrays, object, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

***I'm writing this query in yii2 -***

```
$senderInfo[] = Customers::find()->where(['cust_id' => $resShipment['ship_shipper_id'], 'cust_country_code' => Yii::$app->user->identity->country_code])->distinct()->all();
```

***and getting this as a result -***

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( [0] => common\models\Customers Object ( [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [cust_id] => 79 [cust_user_id] => 2 [cust_designation] => Mr [cust_fname] => abcd [cust_mname] => xyz [cust_lname] => xyz [cust_country_code] => 91 [cust_mobile] => 8888888888 [cust_email] => abcdxyz@gmail.com [cust_id_proof] => [cust_country] => [cust_state] => [cust_city] => [cust_location] => [cust_street] => [cust_address] => delhi [cust_pobox] => 02881 [cust_additional_detail] => [cust_picture] => [verified] => Yes [created] => 2016-04-20 14:45:42 [updated] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [deleted] => No ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [cust_id] => 79 [cust_user_id] => 2 [cust_designation] => Mr [cust_fname] => abcd [cust_mname] => xyz [cust_lname] => xyz [cust_country_code] => 91 [cust_mobile] => 8888888888 [cust_email] => abcdxyz@gmail.com [cust_id_proof] => [cust_country] => [cust_state] => [cust_city] => [cust_location] => [cust_street] => [cust_address] => delhi [cust_pobox] => 413714 [cust_additional_detail] => [cust_picture] => [verified] => Yes [created] => 2016-04-20 14:45:42 [updated] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [deleted] => No ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) ) )
```

***But, because of the empty arrays in the start of this array, I can't access the elements. I've to populate it in a for(strictly) loop, after it gets accessible.***

Comment: Try this with use of `asArray()`,  `$senderInfo[] = Customers::find()->where(['cust_id' => $resShipment['ship_shipper_id'], 'cust_country_code' => Yii::$app->user->identity->country_code])->distinct()->asArray()->all();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result in array you can use ActiveRecord function toArray()

```
 $myModel = Customers::find()->
    where(['cust_id' => $resShipment['ship_shipper_id'],
    'cust_country_code' => Yii::$app->user->identity->country_code])->distinct()->all();

$senderInfo = myModel->toArray();
```

Comment: as it's already an array, it gives the following error if used toArray() - `Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object`

Comment: the result of a Model::find()..... ->all() is not an array but a collection of model then if you want convert to array you should use asArray like in commenr above or toArray() like in my answer .. but ..anyway  why you need model converted to array?

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. But I found another way to solve my problem. So, now I'm not using this query. Anyway, thanks for the help.